# Kali Linux & Metasploitable VirtualBox VMs not getting IP addresses with Bridged adapter

Tags: kali-linux, windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, internet

[image][image]I'm making a hackers lab, so I downloaded Kali Linux and Metasploitable and set them on VirtualBox running on a Windows 10 host machine. The host system is using a wired connection, which both guests also must use. The host has full internet access.

When I configure the VM network interfaces in NAT mode, they get IP addresses and access to the internet, but the lab requires using a Bridged network. When I configure them as bridged adapters,  For Bridged connection I select "Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller" with promiscuous mode set to "deny" and "Cable connected" ticked. In both systems `ifconfig` shows eth0 doesn't even get an IP address.

Metasploitable doesn't have a GUI. Kali does not change to wired network and show me the available networks because I also use a WIFI adapter, it says wired connection 1, but does not work and the network symbol is spinning and it cannot connect to the internet.

I tried changing the adapter types to all the types there are with promiscous mode: allow VMs, but still nothing worked.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us (a lot) more detail. Are you installing metasploitable or Kali? Are these virtual machines or not? If yes, who is the host and who is the client? What "little circle"? What are your current network settings and network layout? What should they be instead? What errors do you get ("cannot use the broswer" doesn't tell us anything: does the browser not load or does it not open webpages? Is it a DNS issue? Something else?). The more detail you give us, the better your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: There, i rewrote it, this is the best i can do, english is not my first language

Comment: Don't worry about the English, your English is fine! It's the lack of information that is problematic. We need to know what is the host machine, and what is the VM. A screenshot of the relevant settings would also be helpful. We need to know what network you are changing to bridged. We also need to know if the host can connect to the internet, and any other relevant information.

Comment: Host machine: windows 10 pro VM: virtualbox running kali linux and metasploitable. I dont know how to answer to the "network im changing". Yes the host machine(windows 10 pro) can connect to the internet.

Comment: Probably problem releted to PCIe passthrough or whatever the reason most Kali VM questions are asked for.

Comment: I'm sorry,  u that does not help me! I dont understand what you meant by it. I'm looking for a fix

Comment: I added to the question new info from your comments and the closed duplicate. I also added from your original question the answer to why a bridged connection is needed. The edit will become available if a senior community member approves it - please verify that the info is correct, if not edit it. Please add also the requested info like the screenshots. When you configure a VM with a Bridged adapter, VirtualBox defaults to Intel PRO/1000 - why are you changing that to Realtek? Have you tested the Intel option? Have you tested with promiscuous mode allowed for VMs?

Comment: No, Realtek is the name that shows up after I change the network settings to bridged adapter, however the adapter type is Intel PRO/1000 as default and I haven't changed it. And yes I did try changing the promiscuous mode to allow VMs

Comment: Well, I put in the screenshots, and mabye some more info, I don't remember. Any help with my problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Just two simple methods you apply on your virtual machine.

**Method 1**: File>Preferences>Network>+Add NAT Network>OK
Go to Metasploitable>Setting>Network>Attach to: Nat Network and Name: NatNetwork>Advance>Promiscuous mode: Allow VMs>OK

**Method 2**: File>Preferences>Network>+Add NAT Network>Edit Network and Change: **Network CIDR 192.168.10.0/24>OK**
Go to Metasploitable>Setting>Network>Attach to: NAT Network and Name: NatNetwork>Advance>Promiscuous mode: Allow VMs>OK

Note: if can't change Metasploitable IP address, type the command: **`sudo dhclient`** and type password change IP address.

Now you go to Kali terminal and ping the Metasploitable IP.

Watch [the "Installation of Metasploitable 2
and connecting it with Kali in VirtualBox" video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pre9yWxjjrk)

Comment: I find your instructions ("Method 1" and "Method 2") to be hard to read.   Please try to make them clearer, perhaps by adding formatting (e.g., separate steps on separate lines) and/or adding words.